# Using Ehcache in a static context

Tags: java, caching, static, ehcache

I'm currently writing a library which has a singleton as the base class.

I'd like to be able to implement a caching system using `Ehcache`, but I'm aware that the cache manager needs to be shut down properly. As static classes when compiled are in the code segment of memory and aren't actually garbage collected I can't shut down on a destructor.

Is there anything funky that might happen if I don't shutdown `Ehcache` assuming I"m not using the persistence functionalities?

Comment: Your JVM will not exit if you do not shut down ehcache cache manager. But you can register shutdown hook to do that

Comment: could i not just do a dirty shutdown if I don't need persistence?

Comment: You can try, but there might be an issue if you configure cache to overflow to filesystem.